# Selenium Python and Beautiful Soup not finding the correct element with href?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, href

I am working on a webscraper that navigates into a page with a list of links, then I use Beautiful Soup to retrieve each of the href. However, when I use Selenium again to try to locate those elements and click them, it is not able to find them.

What I am trying with is this. My href being stored in the variable link:

```
a=self.drive.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[@href=link]")
```

Then I tried with the method *contains*

```
a=self.drive.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(@href,link)]")
```

But now, the seven different links always point to the same element. The links are long and only differ between them by a number. Does that affect how the method *contains* work? For instance:

```
...1953102711/?refId=3fa3c155-c1ed-4322-9390-c9f16320dc76&trk=flagship3_search_srp_jobs
...1981395917/?refId=3fa3c155-c1ed-4322-9390-c9f16320dc76&trk=flagship3_search_srp_jobs
```

What can I do to either, find the element by using the exact search, or avoid repetition using contains?

Comment: If more than on element match the criteria of `find_element` only the first one is returned.

Comment: You should use `find_elements` instead of `find_element` in your code.